# batch rename files according to filenames in another folder with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a big amount of files in a folder named "01-aaa-bbb-ccc", "02-ddd-eee-fff" and so on. In another folder I have an early version of the same files without the index (that was added manually in order to sort them in a specific order) "aaa-bbb-ccc", "ddd-eee-fff". I'd like to use the early version but I need to rename them adding the same index as in the other folder.

Basically, something like: rename the files in folder b in the same way as the onse in folder a if the filename without the index is the same.

Is there a way to do it in powershell? Unfortunately my skills are not good enough for that.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar approach.  Works in my small bit of testing:

```
$newNames = Get-ChildItem ..\a -Name
# Cd into b dir
Get-ChildItem | Foreach {$name = $newNames -match "\d+-$_";if ($name){$_}} | 
                Rename-Item -NewName {$name}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ht = @{}
Get-ChildItem a\* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name | ForEach-Object {
  $null = $_ -match '(\d+)-(.*)'
  $ht[$Matches[2]] = $Matches[1]
}
Get-ChildItem b\* | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item $_ ($ht[$_.name] + '-' + $_.name) }
```

First I create a hash table which contains a mapping of the file name without the index to the index to use. This is then used to rename the items in folder *b* accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help.I tried but it didn't work: it prepends - to the file name (the files are named now "-aaa-bbb-ccc") but it didn't add the same index number as in the other folder. If I got it right, I substituded a\ with the folder with the index number, and b\ the one without

Comment: @Libero: Indeed that was how I intended it to be used. It worked fine for me, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem .\a\* | Select -Expand Name | %{ $_ -match "([\d]+)-(.+)" }  | `
%{ Rename-Item -WhatIf .\b\$($matches[2]) $matches[0] }
```